# Gradle Apply Plugin only for release or disable plugin for variants

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

I am using a android library name `com.growingio.android:vds-android-agent:1.1.1@aar` . It needs to use a plugin to transform my code in artifact state . The library name is  `com.growingio.android` where buildscipt dependencies is `classpath 'com.growingio.android:vds-gradle-plugin:1.1.1'`

But It took really long time to transform my code after every `installDebug`, while I only want to use this plugin in release variant.

I have use variants to split my code to `debug` and `release` variant. Only in `release` variant, my project use `releaseImplementation` to include their aar. My `debug` variant didn't import or use their code in any ways to speed up my build in `installDebug`. But their plugin just scan and try to transform my code no matter what.

Please know that in my profile report for `installDebug`, their plugin's transform task is most time-consuming.

Can someone help me out here?